# (django-template) link to current page but change values of variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an `archive.html` template that is used by two views: `myapp:paginated_view` and `myapp:whole_view`.

Both views can be shown in a reversed or in a normal way.
Now I want to create a link to change in between the ways.

That means there are four cases: (after the arrow what happens when you click that link)

1. Whole_view & non-reversed -> whole_view and reversed
2. Whole_view & reversed -> whole_view and non-reversed
3. Paged_view & non-reversed -> paged_view (still on same page) and reversed
4. Paged_view & reversed -> paged_view (still on same page) and non-reversed

I wonder if I had to declare all cases with if-clauses in the template or work with absolute url-pathes or create multiple templates, but these are my only ideas. Is there a better way? (I hope for something like: `{% url current_page reverse=not reverse %}`

---

My url conf: (in myapp)

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^archive/(?P<reverse>[n]{0,1})/?$', views.ArchivePagedView.as_view(), name="paged_archive"),
  url(r'^archive/all/(?P<reverse>[n]{0,1})/?$', views.WholeArchiveView.as_view(), name='whole_archive'),
]
```

As you can see, in the url-conf `reverse` can be `n` or it's empty/doesn't exist. In my template it's true or false.

How to deal with this?

Comment: The best place to deal with it is in the view code. A common use is to pass arguments as url parameters, like this: `example.com/archive/all/?reversed&paginate`. These will be passed to the view as a QueryDict accessed as `request.GET`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Comment: And how do I do this? If you can put this into a good answer and it works, that'll be the accepted one.